# How to make the content in a table to be centred?

Tags: tables

I have 2 questions:

1. How to make the content to be in the middle?
   I had change from      `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}` to      `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|}` but it seemed not working.

I want to maximum the size of my pages

2. Why the content does not take in `\textit{datafeature_1}[\, \_,\_  ]\,`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\textit{datafeature_1}[\, \_,\_  ]\,

 \begin{table}[h!]
 \centering
     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
      \hline
    A & B & C \\
       \hline
    % {\textit{datafeature_1}[\, \_,\_  ]\}, &  B & C
    % %   \hline
     \end{tabularx}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On your second question: An unescaped `_` (underscore) character is not allowed to occur in text mode.

Comment: To have the contents of an `X` column centred, use in the table preamble `>{\centering\arraybackslash}X`

Comment: @Mico, anyway to have `_` (underscore) to put inside a table?

Comment: @aan - Then you must escape the `_` character -- exactly as you already do with the other instances of the underscore characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your two issues you can do the following:

1. Add `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` before your `X` column or better define a new column like

   ```
   \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
   ```
2. Your code `\textit{datafeature_1}[\, \_,\_  ]\,` is wrong at the first `_`: it is interpreted to write an index (for that you need to write `$_1$`; thats the reason for the error message about a missing `$`). But you want to write an underscore, so escape the `_` like `\_`. So use the code `\textit{datafeature\_1}[\, \_,\_  ]\,` before table and in table!

Remark: I added

```
\usepackage{showframe} % <=============== to visualize typing area and margins
```

to show you that you do not need command `\centering` in the table, because `\textwidth` forces the table to span the complete available text width ...

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe} % <=============== to visualize typing area and margins

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % <====================


\begin{document}

text \textit{datafeature\_1}[\, \_, \_  ]\, text % <====================

\begin{table}[h!]
%\centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|C|C|}
    \hline
    A & B & C \\
    \hline
    {\textit{datafeature\_1}[\, \_, \_  ]\,} &  B & C \\ % <===========
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: I still cannot get the meaning of this `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}` any good easy explanation documentation for this?

Comment: @aan You can have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2802895  or https://texfaq.org/FAQ-tabcellalign and it be in a good latex introduction ( I guess a german one does not help you?) ...

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, the `X` column type fully justifies the contents of the cell, starting from the left. I suggest you add the instruction

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

in the preamble and replace

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
```

with

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|C|C|}
```

Note that `{\textit{datafeature_1}[\, \_,\_  ]\}` contains 2 [!] errors: (i) the first instance of `_` isn't escaped; (ii) the opening `{` curly brace is not terminated properly, since `\}` *typesets* a curly brace. Depending on what you want to achieve, either replace `{` with `\{` or, alternatively, replace `\}` with `}`.

Comment: thanks. Actually I want [datafeature_1] [_,_] in my table, like the picture

Comment: @aan - Then why aren't you writing `[datafeature\_1] [,]`? By the way, the screenshot does *not* show `[datafeature_1] [,]`.